# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 WH'at line 14

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am getting error

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

I am a beginner  CodeIgniter , but when I try to make an error like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Vmp.jpg)

My Controller

```
public function cari_cetak($kode) {
        $QuerySaya      = $this->db->query(
                          "SELECT A.*,B.nm_agama,C.nm_jenis,D.nama_kelurahan,K.nm_jurusan,
                            E.nama_kecamatan,F.nama_kota,G.nama_propinsi, H.*,I.*,
                            YEAR(curdate()) - YEAR(A.tanggal_lahir) AS usia,J.nama_status
                            FROM (((((((((t_pegawai A 
                            INNER JOIN t_agama B          ON A.kd_agama=B.kd_agama)
                            LEFT JOIN t_pegawai_status J  ON A.id_status=J.id_status)
                            LEFT JOIN t_jenis C           ON A.id_jenis=C.id_jenis)
                            LEFT JOIN alamat_kelurahan D  ON A.id_kelurahan=D.id_kelurahan)
                            LEFT JOIN alamat_kecamatan E  ON D.id_kecamatan=E.id_kecamatan)
                            LEFT JOIN alamat_kota F       ON E.id_kota=F.id_kota)
                            LEFT JOIN alamat_propinsi G   ON F.id_propinsi=G.id_propinsi)
                            LEFT JOIN t_riwayat_pangkat H ON A.id_pegawai=H.id_pegawai)
                            LEFT JOIN t_pangkat I         ON H.id_pangkat=I.id_pangkat)
                            LEFT JOIN t_prodi K           ON A.id_prodi=K.id_prodi)
                            LEFT JOIN t_jurusan L         ON K.id_jurusan=L.id_jurusan)
                            WHERE A.sts_pegawai<>'1' AND A.id_pegawai='$kode' 
                            ORDER BY A.nm_pegawai;"
                        );
        return $QuerySaya->result();
    }
```

Comment: You are 2 ( short

Comment: Your FROM clause is misformatted. Check the mysql manual for the proper syntax. Its is hard to provide any more help without knowing what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: There are 2 missing ( in your query

Comment: What have you tried to debug this query? Why not start with removing line by line to see where that error occurs. Additionally, this code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: What kind of LISP MySQL mutant is this? Why do you need so many parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 missing "(" in your query. Try this:

```
"SELECT A.*,B.nm_agama,C.nm_jenis,D.nama_kelurahan,K.nm_jurusan,
                            E.nama_kecamatan,F.nama_kota,G.nama_propinsi, H.*,I.*,
                            YEAR(curdate()) - YEAR(A.tanggal_lahir) AS usia,J.nama_status
                            FROM 
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        (
                                            (
                                                (
                                                (
                                                    (
                                                        ( 
                                                                (
                                                                    (   t_pegawai A 
                                                                    INNER JOIN t_agama B          ON A.kd_agama=B.kd_agama
                                                                    )
                                                                    LEFT JOIN t_pegawai_status J  ON A.id_status=J.id_status
                                                                )
                                                                LEFT JOIN t_jenis C           ON A.id_jenis=C.id_jenis
                                                            )
                                                            LEFT JOIN alamat_kelurahan D  ON A.id_kelurahan=D.id_kelurahan
                                                        )
                                                        LEFT JOIN alamat_kecamatan E  ON D.id_kecamatan=E.id_kecamatan
                                                    )
                                                    LEFT JOIN alamat_kota F       ON E.id_kota=F.id_kota
                                                    )
                                                LEFT JOIN alamat_propinsi G   ON F.id_propinsi=G.id_propinsi
                                            )
                                            LEFT JOIN t_riwayat_pangkat H ON A.id_pegawai=H.id_pegawai
                                        )
                                        LEFT JOIN t_pangkat I         ON H.id_pangkat=I.id_pangkat
                                    )
                                    LEFT JOIN t_prodi K           ON A.id_prodi=K.id_prodi
                                )
                               LEFT JOIN t_jurusan L         ON K.id_jurusan=L.id_jurusan
                            )
                            WHERE A.sts_pegawai<>'1' AND A.id_pegawai='$kode' 
                            ORDER BY A.nm_pegawai;"
```